# jQuery - End setInterval Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running the following.

```
setInterval(function()
{
    update(url, baseName(data));
}
, 1000);
```

This calls that `update` function every second.

Is there a way to keep this functionality of calling `update` every second, but killing it or ending it after 10 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a counter and store the interval reference, then use clearInterval() to end the calls

```
var counter = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    counter++;
    update(url, baseName(data));
    if(counter>=10){
        clearInterval(timer)
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep a counter:

```
var timesCalled = 0;

var t = setInterval(function() {
    update(url, baseName(data));
    timesCalled++;

    if (timesCalled === 10)
        clearInterval(t);
}, 1000);
```

[(`clearInterval`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval)